# How to determine membership on transaction dates using SQL?

Tags: sql, date, join

I have two very large tables in a DB.

One is regarding membership and when users were members:

```
User|Date|Membership
1111|2020-12-01 06:00:00|False
1111|2020-12-20 18:00:00|True
1111|2020-12-30 12:00:00|False
2222|2020-12-01 06:00:00|True
2222|2020-12-20 18:00:00|False
2222|2020-12-30 12:00:00|True
...
```

And the other is regarding those users' transactions:

```
User|Date|Transaction
1111|2020-12-02 06:00:00|3.00
1111|2020-12-19 18:00:00|2.00
1111|2020-12-29 12:00:00|4.00
2222|2020-12-02 06:00:00|1.00
2222|2020-12-19 18:00:00|2.00
2222|2021-01-06 12:00:00|4.00
...
```

I'd like to determine if the user was a member or not when they made the transaction with a new field in the latter table that, in this case, would be the following:

```
User|Date|Transaction|Was_Member
1111|2020-12-02 06:00:00|3.00|False
1111|2020-12-19 18:00:00|2.00|False
1111|2020-12-29 12:00:00|4.00|True
2222|2020-12-02 06:00:00|1.00|True
2222|2020-12-19 18:00:00|2.00|True
2222|2021-01-06 12:00:00|4.00|True
...
```

How can I efficiently do something like this in SQL where I stitch time ranges together in order to detect membership? Any SQL language is fine, just want to understand the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can join two tables based on dates (less than) and find the latest record using analytical function as follows:

```
select user, date, transaction, membership as was_member from
(select t.user, t.date, t.transaction, m.membership,
       row_number() over (partition by t.user, t.date order by m.date desc) as rn
  from membership m join transactions t
    on t.user = m.user and t.date >= m.date) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Was just writing the same. Should be `t.date >= m.date` no?

Comment: Can also be written as a correlated subquery or an apply/lateral. Depends on size of set and indexes as to whether it's more performant

Comment: Yeap, as per the requirement. I written the code based on my understanding from sample data. OP can change some of the conditions according to requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *,
    Was_member =
    (SELECT TOP 1 membership
    FROM membership m
    WHERE m.user = t.user
        AND t.date <= m.date)
FROM transaction t;
```

This needs good indexing and a small transaction set to work well.

This can also be done with a row number solution, which may be more performant for large sets or bad indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this simplest with a `left join`:

```
select t.*, m.was_member
from transactions t join
     (select m.*, lead(date) over (partition by user order by date) as next_date
      from members m
     ) m
     on t.user = m.user and
        t.date >= m.date and
        (t.date < m.next_date or m.next_date is null);
```

For performance, you want an index on `members(user, date)`.

There may be more efficient methods, depending on what you mean by "very large tables", how the data is structured, and what database you are using.